# Where can I found some of my old question?

Tags: support

I asked once why most sunday school version of the Solomon story doesn't mention that the 2 women that come to Solomon is prostitute.

I think I got good answers there that I want to quote for my book, "From faith to doubt". I lost the questions though. Can I still see it? I'd like to quote the answers.

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: The question you speak of was downvoted to -10, which is one of the lowest scores of any question. The downvotes were a good sign that the question was low-quality, and it was deleted a month after it was asked and closed. If you still really want to see it though, we moderators could provide a link to it.

Comment: Please provide a link to it.

Answer (score 3):

It is not SE's responsibility to host and archive anybody's junk. This is a curated library of data. I do not see any reason content this network has deemed unsuitable for publication should be dredged up for such a purpose.

If you want to use this site as a research resource it is certainly an appropriate venue for that and the content licence allows it, but you would need to ask questions the community approves of. This usually means you need to frame reasonably well thought out, respectful questions with suitable scope. The closure and -10 voting pattern and subsequent deletion are a pretty good indication that wasn't happening in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all of your question from your profile - or anyone else's questions and answers from their profile.  You can click your own name or follow [this link](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/8667/sharen-eayrs?tab=questions&sort=votes#sharen-eayrs?tab=questions&sort=newest&_suid=139839210062107026314665865025).

Comment: It's deleted. I do not see those questions again.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that there is still a question that wasn't Deleted,

[Why Can Prostitutes Come to Solomon?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/22959/4158)

is this the question that you seek?

Comment: No, there was another one after that -- a sort of follow up but as it was closed and later deleted on account of being largely composed of invective rhetoric.

Comment: this question seems to have a high quality answer though....